# External hard disk detection issue

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

**what exactly happened:** 
I have a Seagate 1 TB external hard disk.It was working fine till now.The problem started when I plugged it in my android phone and then back in my pc then simply *it does not showup anywhere* and :

1. It does not appear in file explorer [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAVsb.png)
2. It does not appear in disk management [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehYpj.png)
3. It is not listed in Diskpart command [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL8Tu.png)
4. It only appears in Device Manager under disk drives [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKLvT.png)
5. It does not appear in BIOS
6. only makes sound when plugged and unplugged.
7. disk spins and light is also showing.

.

**What I already tried:**

1. updated usb drivers.
2. used new cable also.
3. plugged in another pc
4. usb mass storage is also enabled in BIOS
5. no issue in any usb port 
   Anything else i can do?

Comment: Seems like the disk is dead and should be replaced. I suggest not plugging the replacement again into the phone.

Comment: How it can be dead , as disk was working fine with both phone and pc but now not detected in pc or phone.

Comment: Almost all dead disks worked correctly just before they died... Seriously, some circuit in the disk probably got fried. It might have been sub-standard to start with.

Comment: But It does show up in Device Manager...also disk light turns on when plugged in

Comment: You wrote: "It does **not** appear in disk management".

Comment: True, it does NOT appear in disk management but it does appear in Device Manager under disk drives....check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKLvT.png

Comment: Is that a 2.5" or 3.5" disk?

Comment: 2.5 Seagate 1Tb..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the disk is dead and should be replaced.

The only place it is shown, in the Device Manager, it appears under a very generic name.
The USB disk controller interface is identified, but no disk is found on it.

Some circuit on the disk was fried, or the firmware of the disk was damaged.
You could get in touch with Seagate to ask for a utility that could rewrite
the disk firmware, but I'm not too hopeful for that.

If you go for a replacement disk, I suggest not plugging it again into the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Disk's controller is dead or in failure mode. You can't fix it.

It's a 2.5" drive so it doesn't have external power supply. The phone may not be able to deliver enough power, leading to this corruption.

If the USB interface isn't integrated with the internal disk, but attached using a SATA adapter, you may be able to pull your data from the disk by detaching the adapter and plugging the disk directly into a desktop computer or another adapter. It's unlikely though, nearly all 2.5" external drives and even some 3.5" drives use integrated adapters nowadays. If that's the case, you'll need professional data recovery service to get your data.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I thought my disk was dead when was not.

Because I used really bad chinese SATA adapter. Once I've connected it to the primary SATA in my notebook everything  worked again.

However, plugging and unplugging your hard disk with bad adapters may lead your hard disk to corrupt easily.